# Content alignment inside wrapper

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm reaching this sketch:

[image]

how I can push image towards bottom, then I can align content noramally. For some unknown reason for me, content reacting like a row, not a column

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    <div class="premises">
        <div class="left-wrapper">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/riJ1LKY.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="right-wrapper align-self-end">
            <div class="title">
                <p class="">Title text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="ordered-data d-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <p class="">**.**.**</p>
                <p class="">**:** - **:**</p>
            </div>   <div class="destination d-inline-flex justify-content-start">
                <p class="">Destination</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-options d-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <p class="">Submit</p>
                <p class="">Cancel</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1bpm5v9b/3/)

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the end result to look like? It's not entirely clear from your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your `.premises` should have `flex-direction: row;` (or remove it for default behaviour) to get closer to the result in your original image.
Then you should set a `min-height: 0;` to your left and right wrappers to counter flex's `min-height: auto;` behaviour, and remove the `height: 100%;` as the value isn't explicitly set in the parent. I also recommend setting `vertical-align: bottom;` to your image tag.

Here is an updated, working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ybxbx55m/

Comment: Appreciated! :)